# Winver command anomalous behavior in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've a batch file that has only single command in it.

```
winver
```

When I execute this batch file, nothing shows up but the command seems to execute in an uncontrolled loop.

But when I type `winver` in command prompt, a window opens that shows up the version of the Windows OS I'm currently using. 
My question is why isn't this command working when I place it in batch file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For me it works on Win 8.1. What windows version are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: Maybe try running the batch file with admin rights.

Comment: Yes that's solved. But, what might be the reason the command was executing infinitely without admin rights?

Comment: Was the batch called winver?

Comment: Is your batch file called `winver.bat` or `winver.cmd`? if so, rename it, because otherwise the batch file tries to call itself rather than `winver.exe`. There are definitely no admin. rights required for `winver`!

Comment: @aschipfl, curiously the OP *"solved"* the problem because running the batch file with admin rights changes the default active directory so the batch file does not found itself

Comment: Another way `wmic os get version` and another `systeminfo | Findstr /i "Version"` (this gives BIOS ver as well)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running it with admin rights worked solved the purpose.

Comment: This is not the answer to your problem.  The reason you were seeing the program execute in an uncontrolled loop is because you named the batch file winver.

Answer (score 1):

Use as batch file name different from "winver.bat" with the single line "start winver".
Regards, Erich